# Split method is not working on a string? TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: split

Here is my concerned code:
I am not sure why I am not able to use `split()` on a `string`. I typically use `split()` and it works fine all the time. This is the first time it is not working. Why?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = {
  data: []
}
}

componentDidMount(){
var url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';

fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => data.map((item, index) => {
    return item.name + " " + item.flag;
  })).then(data => this.setState({data}));

}  

render() {
  var randItems = [];
  var randNum = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.data.length);
    randItems.push(this.state.data[randNum]);
  }


var item = randItems[0].split(' ');
console.log('typeof item and its value ' + typeof item + ' ' + item);
```

Take note that the output is typeof `item` and its value `string` is

> Northern Mariana Islands 
>   https://restcountries.eu/data/mnp.svg

Comment: You `randItems` variable is local inside the `render` method, so where do you expect the `randItems` outside of that to come from?